# Loop MySQL run with java

Tags: java, mysql, loops, stored-procedures, optimization

I have 3 tables having the following content :

```
Author
idAuthor INT
name VARCHAR

Publication
idPublication INT
Title VARCHAR
Date YEAR
Type VARCHAR
Conference

author_has_publication
author_idAuthor INT
publication_idPublication INT
```

I am trying to do relational schema on the authors. The objectif is to show the number of publication they have in common. The authors name are parameters, I can have up to 8 names. My code is giving the number of common publication between 2 authors, so i have to loop it. I am currently using a Java loop and SQL statement to do that. Here is the SQL part

```
private int runQuery(String a1, String a2){ // a1 author 1 and a2 author 2
        try {
            auth1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "ROOT");
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();


            String queryUpdate1 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp1;";
            String queryUpdate2 = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp2;";
            String queryUpdate3 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS (SELECT Author.name, Publication.idPublication, Publication.title FROM Author INNER JOIN Author_has_Publication ON Author_has_Publication.author_idAuthor=author.idAuthor INNER JOIN Publication ON Author_has_Publication.publication_idPublication=publication.idPublication WHERE Author.name='"+ a1+"');";
            String queryUpdate4 = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp2 AS (SELECT Author.name, Publication.idPublication, Publication.title FROM Author INNER JOIN Author_has_Publication ON Author_has_Publication.author_idAuthor=author.idAuthor INNER JOIN Publication ON Author_has_Publication.publication_idPublication=publication.idPublication WHERE Author.name='"+ a2+"');";
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT temp1.title from temp1 INNER JOIN temp2 on temp1.idPublication = temp2.idPublication) as t;";

            stmt.executeUpdate(queryUpdate1);
            stmt.executeUpdate(queryUpdate2);
            stmt.executeUpdate(queryUpdate3);
            stmt.executeUpdate(queryUpdate4);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            int result = -1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                result = rs.getInt(1);
            }

            System.out.println("result = " + result);
            long end = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            queryTimeLabel.setText("Query Execution Time :"+end);
            connection.close();
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Here is the loop part (to repeat the SQL when there are more than 2 authors given) and generate the graph :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    graph = new mxGraph();
    Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();
    authVertex = getAuthors();



    // ///////////////////////////////////
    // CREATES GRAPH, Graph only shows up after you resize the window
    graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
    try {

        int i = 0;
        for(String a: authVertex.keySet()){
            int j = 0;
            for(String b: authVertex.keySet()){
                if(j > i) {
                    graph.insertEdge(parent, null, String.valueOf(runQuery(a,b)), authVertex.get(a), authVertex.get(b)); // loop the SQL statement 2 by 2.
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    } finally {
        graph.getModel().endUpdate();
    }

    graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
    graphPan.removeAll();
    graphPan.add(graphComponent);
    setVisible(true);
    // /////////////////////////////////////////


}
```

My code is currently working, but I would like to know if it was possible to increase the performance by passing everything into MySQL, that means that I enter the authors name in parameter and the loop is hangled by MySQL, I check the MySQL procedure but my issue is how to handle the authors names parameter as it is a variable.

Comment: read up on JOIN

Comment: You should use `Prepared` statements.If you have not considered about this i can write an answer about it, and several performance improvements techniques.

Comment: I think you can do it using sub queries and joins.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, the current code is already using joins and subquery

Comment: No i haven't considered prepared statements

Comment: But you should. Prepared statements are a must, if you want performance and safety against SQL injection. Don't even try without them. The next step would be batching.

Answer (score 0):

One way, in a single statement:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  Author_has_Publication AS ap1
    JOIN  Author_has_Publication AS ap2  ON ap1.publication_idPublication =
                                            ap2.publication_idPublication
    JOIN  Author AS a1  ON ap1.author_idAuthor = a1.id_Author
    JOIN  Author AS a2  ON ap2.author_idAuthor = a2.id_Author
    WHERE  a1.name = '...'
      AND  a2.name = '...'
```

Another way may be

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
    FROM  
    (
        SELECT  ahp.publication_idPublication, COUNT(*)
            FROM  Author_has_Publication AS ahp
            JOIN  Author AS a  ON a.id_Author = ahp.author_idAuthor
            WHERE  a.name IN ('...', '...')
            GROUP BY  ahp.publication_idPublication
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2   -- Number of authors
    ) x
```

Composite indexes needed:

```
Author_has_Publication:  (author_idAuthor, publication_idPublication)
Author_has_Publication:  (publication_idPublication, author_idAuthor)
Author:  (name, id)
```

Note: Each technique can be rather easily extended to more than 2 authors.  The second query could even be adapted to "at least 3 of these 5 authors": 5 names in `IN` and `HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3`.